How can I automatically generate unique PDF filenames in LyX?
I've been using LyX 2.4 (windows 11) with the XeLaTeX engine.I've been using LyX with the XeLaTeX engine, and every time I press Ctrl+R to create a PDF, I end up overwriting the previous file.
I’d like each new PDF to have a unique name to avoid this issue. I'm hoping to achieve this without using batch scripts or additional files. Any suggestions on how to configure this within LyX?

BTW: To avoid misunderstandings, you should always explain the problem in the text of the question and also add the question there — not only in the title. At present, the question at the end of the description could be misinterpreted as: How to configure LyX to use XeLaTeX? With this you could also shorten the title into something like “How to generate unique PDF filenames using LyX?”. Short titles are IMHO more striking.

which operating system are you using?

AFAIK, LyX itself does not offer an automatic option for this. However, you can use File → Export → PDF (XeTeX) and choose the file name yourself. If you perform the export from the command line, you can also automate the selection of a new name. For example, if you call the following Linux/Unix shell script with the name of the LyX file, a document with a new name is generated each time depending on the date and time:
#!/bin/sh
destname=${1%.lyx}-`date +%s`.pdf
lyx $1 --export-to default "${destname}"

A similar PowerShell script would be (tested only with Linux but should work with Windows too):
$FileNoExt = Split-Path -Path $args[0] -LeafBase
$UniqueString = Get-Date -UFormat "%s"
lyx $args[0] --export-to default "$FileNoExt-$UniqueString.pdf"

The filename would change every second, which should be unique enough.

I don’t do the whole command-line exporting thing, but it still sounds like pure genius!, thanks!
